# Android custom Preference: Where to put code for cleanup?

Tags: android, design-patterns, sharedpreferences, preference, resource-cleanup

I'm creating a custom `android.preference.Preference` and in the constructor I need to register a listener for changes in `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class MyPreference extends Preference {
    private final SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mListener;

    public MyPreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ...;
        mListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                // listener implementation
            }
        };

        sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);
    }
```

According to [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening), it's a good idea to complement the call to the `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`  with the call to the `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` in the `onPause()` method:

> For proper lifecycle management in the activity, we recommend that you
>   register and unregister your
>   SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener during the
>   onResume() and onPause() callbacks, respectively:

Since `Preference` doesn't provide `onPause()` method for overriding, I'm wondering **what is the best alternative method from which I should call `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` in case of custom `Preference` implementation?**

There are, for instance, `onPrepareForRemoval()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` methods, but I'm not sure if one of them is the proper place to put clean up code into it.

Any thoughts?